# Why doesn't addOns.common.universalActions not need the URL to be in the urlFetchWhitelist list for it to work in a Google Workspace Add-on manifest

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace, google-workspace-add-ons

Google's documentation says that all URLs must be explicitly listed in [`urlFetchWhitelist`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/manifest#Manifest.FIELDS.urlFetchWhitelist).

However, I have a URL in `universalActions` and it works, even though I don't have the URL in `urlFetchWhitelist`. What am I misunderstanding?

```
{
    "timeZone": "America/New_York",
    "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
    "runtimeVersion": "V8",
    "oauthScopes": [],
    "addOns": {
        "common": {
            "universalActions": [
                {
                    "label": "About",
                    "openLink": "https://github.com/imthenachoman/Gmail-Auto-Vacation-Responder"
                }
            ]
        },
        "gmail": {},
        "calendar": {}
    }
}
```

Comment: In the documentation you refer says: `If present, any URL endpoint fetched must match one of the prefixes in this list.` this means that, **only** if the parameter is present, the verification will be executed, in any other case, not... Is this what you are asking or am I missing something?

Comment: I thought it's an allow list meaning the default is a deny list. So if the parameter is missing or empty then it won't work.

Comment: From https://developers.google.com/apps-script/manifest/allowlist-url: `In both cases you must allowlist the URLs you open or fetch from in the project manifest.`

Comment: If my answer has been helpful to you, please consider accepting it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/how-tos/universal-actions):

> Universal actions are menu item elements that allow a user to open a new web page, display new UI cards, or run a specific Apps Script function when selected. In operation they are very similar to card actions, except that universal actions are always placed on every card in your add-on, regardless of the current add-on context.

The scope of the Unversal Actions is already defined inside the `appscript.json`, so it would not make sense to include it again inside the [`urlFetchWhiteList`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/manifest#Manifest.FIELDS.urlFetchWhitelist). As you can read in the documentation:

> Universal actions are configured in your add-on's project manifest. Once you've configured a universal action, it is always available to users of your add-on.

In short, Universal Actions are intended for actions that do not depend on the current execution context, and that are available from anywhere in the add-on. For any other type of request, for example, interacting with an external API, the urls of that API should be included in the `urlFetchWhiteList`.

Comment: I see. That is a bit confusing. `so it would not make sense to include it again inside the urlFetchWhiteList` -- but so would any other URL in the script/project. It doesn't make sense. I would expect all URLs should be in the allow list. Thanks!

Comment: To make it less confusing, anything that you call using `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` needs to be in this list.